# DEFLATE is not working on Apache 2.4 under Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-services, ubuntu

It's weird, the .htaccess code was working on CentOS & Apache 2.2, but we have migrated into Ubuntu and Apache 2.4 the compression stopped to work.

But checking the Google PageSpeed Insights, says that the compression is not working.

This is our .htaccess code

```
# Deflate Compression by FileType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
Addtype font/opentype .otf
Addtype font/truetype .ttf
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# Deflate Compression by MimeType</span>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|txt|html|ttf|otf)$”>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|ttf|otf)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^font/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```